# Using reflection and LINQ how can I select the alias for columns and add a new column based on condition?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

```
    public class School
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public int Children { get; set; }
    }

    public Func<string, object, object> someMethod = SomeMethod;
    public static object SomeMethod(string name, object value)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<School> ls = new List<School>();
        School s = new School();
        s.Name = "s1";
        s.Active = true;
        s.Children = 10;
        ls.Add(s);

        s = new School();
        s.Name = "s2";
        s.Active = false;
        s.Children = 5;
        ls.Add(s);


        IEnumerable<object> rows = ls;


        var result = rows.Select(
            x => x.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => someMethod(p.Name, p.GetValue(x, null)))); 

    }
```

Note:
rows can be anything
The result should like this:

Name Active Children New_Column
s1   true   10       ?? for example if active=true then display Ok

Comment: What is your question? It is not entirely clear what you are trying to do with that code, `result` will be an `IEnumerable<object>` containing 2 1s

Comment: The result should be in tabular format: Name Active Children New_Column with their values

Comment: Based on my interpretation of your question, you're trying to return a new type with dynamically created properties. For that, you may want to look into code that creates a new type at runtime. There are various approaches to solving that which work.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, I just want to return all rows and columns from school list and in the result I want to a add a new column and the corresponding value is set based on a condition (like Active = false). Note IEnumerable<object> rows can contains data from other type and I want to set a condition dynamical.